# JTest - variable may possibly be null in try catch block

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, nullpointerexception, jtest

I have the code as below:

```
object a = getObjectFromBlahBlah(); //'a' may possibly be null

try{
    a.beginTransaction();
    .
    .
    .

} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.debug(e.getMessage());
}
```

After I run JTest, it will warn me `'a' may possibly be null`. I don't want to do one more checking like `if (a == null) return;` since I already cover the `NullPointerException` in the try/catch block. Can anyone explain what happen to this? How I can get rid of this warning from JTest by alter the code?

Comment: Explain what? Why your IDE is warning you?

Comment: @AlexandreSantos yes, so I can know what I have to do with it.

Comment: So simply don't care it.

Comment: @suninsky that JTest rules is setup for code review and audit purpose, can't simply ignore it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How I can get rid of this warning from JTest by alter the code?

You said it yourself: you need to check `a == null`. JTest doesn't care that you "already cover the NullPointerException" in the current configuration. I don't know if it can be set up to recognize this, but presumably you also aren't allowed to change its configuration, given

> that JTest rules is setup for code review and audit purpose, can't simply ignore it:)

If it's acceptable for the audit, you can also [suppress the message directly](http://www.technology.heartland.edu/courses/Computer%20Science/Programming/Java%20Courses/JTest%20User%27s%20Guide/supp_sa.htm) and include the reason.

Also, I hope

```
catch (Exception e) {
    logger.debug(e.getMessage());
}
```

is just a simplification and wouldn't pass any code review or audit!